# How to generate only so many permutations more efficiently in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, permutation, unordered-set

I'm trying to solve a problem and I feel like I'm really close to it but it's still a little slow because I'm generating so many permutations.

I need the permutations of "0123456789". I know there are **(10)!** permutations which is a lot. 
I use an `std::unordered_set` because I don't care about the order they are stored in and it seemed faster than using a regular `std::set`

**Here is some core I wrote:** `max_perm_size` is the size of the string of permutations I care about for a particular case.

```
void getPermutations(unordered_set<string> &permutations, int &max_perm_size)
{
    string digits = "0123456789";

    do{

        permutations.insert(digits.substr(0, max_perm_size));

    } while (next_permutation(digits.begin(), digits.end()));

}
```

**I have two main questions about this code:**

1. Above I'm still generating then entire "0123456789" permutation even for cases where I only care about permutations of size `max_perm_size`. I just trim them afterwords before storing them into my `std::unordered_set`. Is there a way to do this in a better way so it's faster?
2. For the worst case `max_pem_size = 10`, is there a more efficient way for me to generate and store all of these permutations in general?

Comment: I should be missing something... Do you really want permutations? If so why are you using an unordered set to return them? Do you not want combinations instead?

Comment: Without even looking at the algorithm, it looks like you just want to fill your data structure with numbers and maybe iterate over it later. A `unordered_set<string>` will positively destroy your cache, try with a `vector<int>` if at all possible.

Comment: @olivecoder I believe I want the permutations, yes.

Comment: @tux3 The reason Im using a set is because using a vector I would have to check the vector every time to make sure I dont add repeated permutations. For instance if I need the permutations that are only of size 2, 
I would get (01) a bunch of times before getting to (02) and so on. The set only stores the ones that arent already in the set/

Comment: @JerryCoffin I see what you are saying, I think that's kind of the direction im looking for. The problem I was running into is that say I want all permutations of size 2. I need {(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)...(1,0).(1,2)...(1,8)...(9,1)...(9,8)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as a I can tell, your result is numbers (without repeated digits) from 0 through some limit. Since you say you don't care about the order of the digits, it's probably easiest if we just stick to ascending ones. That being the case, we can generate results like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        for (int j=i+1; j<10; j++)
            for (int k=j+1; k<10; k++)
                std::cout << i << j << k << "\t";
}
```

Result:

```
012     013     014     015     016     017     018     019     023     024     025     026     027
028     029     034     035     036     037     038     039     045     046     047     048     049
056     057     058     059     067     068     069     078     079     089     123     124     125
126     127     128     129     134     135     136     137     138     139     145     146     147
148     149     156     157     158     159     167     168     169     178     179     189     234
235     236     237     238     239     245     246     247     248     249     256     257     258
259     267     268     269     278     279     289     345     346     347     348     349     356
357     358     359     367     368     369     378     379     389     456     457     458     459
467     468     469     478     479     489     567     568     569     578     579     589     678
679     689     789
```

If your limit isn't a number of digits, you can put the digits together into an actual int and compare (then break out of the loops).

Comment: I really like this way of producing the permutations. But I need to be able to produce permutations of up to size 10. So how would I make this code be scalable like that? to where it can also return `0123  0124  0125...`
all the way up to when I need `0123456789  0123456798...`

Comment: I guess I should let you know what I'm trying to accomplish, this is not for homework, I'm doing this because I want to get better at coding.

Given a string 'STRING' I need to be able to generate all the possible permutations of digits(0-9) which can represent this string. No two characters can have the same digit representation. and strings will have up to 10 unique characters. Don't worry about how to check if the permutations are a valid solution, I already wrote that part of the code and it works. I need to find all the possible solutions though so I need to  generate every permutation.

Comment: @aSilveira: As it stands, you need loops nested to the depth of the number of digits you need. The easy way to get away from that is to make it recursive instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to your case, not a general solution, but for the case of digit permutations, you can do:

```
void getPermutations(unordered_set<string> &permutations, int max_perm_size)
{
    if (max_perm_size < 1) return;

    uint64_t stopat = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < max_perm_size; ++i) {
        stopat *= 10;
    }

    for (uint64_t dig = 0; dig < stopat; ++dig) {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << std::setw(max_perm_size) << std::setfill('0') << dig;
        permutations.insert(ss.str());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you comment a bit on what's going on? Im fairly new to this and Im having a hard time following it.

Comment: @aSilveira: It's just producing all numbers with the required number of digits, and converting them to zero padded strings, which gets permutations of the desired length only, no duplicates generated at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can take a substring of your digits string first.  Then your loop will only deal with permutations of max_perm_size.
2. You could create a class that generates permutations on demand instead of pre-generating and storing them beforehand.  Depending on your application, you may not even have to store them.

Comment: I get what you are saying for part 1 but say I have "0123456789" and I need all the permutations of size 3.
How will I get the permutation "189" for instance.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question.  I would go with counting loops as others have suggested.